# Pushed Django project to GitHub with Pycharm - now not working

Tags: python, django, github

Sorry for the generic question; I'm not sure how to best classify the problem.

I had a Django project that I was working on locally, then I pushed up to GitHub to collaborate with someone (I'm completely new to GitHub). I did this using pycharm and the project was copied into a subdirectory of PycharmProjects. It seemed to work fine. I didn't work on it for a week or so, during which time I upgrated to Catalina.

I've come back to work on the project and it's completely broken! I can't get the development server up and running from either the PycharmProjects directory or my original working directory on the desktop. I suspect in the PycharmProjects folder it's a path or dependency problem, but I didn't change anything in my original folder.

I can activate the virtual environment, then I get these errors:

```
(ll_env) Davids-MacBook-Pro-2:POM_Journal_Club davidhallsworth$ python manage.py runserver
  File "manage.py", line 16
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```
(ll_env) Davids-MacBook-Pro-2:POM_Journal_Club davidhallsworth$ python3 manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 16, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

The repository is available at https://github.com/dchallsworth/POM_Journal_Club

Any help would be massively appreciated!! It's my first project and has taken a lot of time to learn.

Comment: Does you virtualenv have Django installed on it?

Comment: It did, and the new folder bin/lib/python3.7 directory has a django directory in it. However, when I try to reinstall I get: 

```
(ll_env) Davids-MacBook-Pro-2:POM_Journal_Club davidhallsworth$ pip install django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pip", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: You need to check your pip version that is trying to install that. Do you have pip and pip3 on the env? If so, can you try installing with pip3 instead? Looks like a similar issue when installing django 2.x with python 2.x instead of python 3.x.

Comment: Also gets TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

In my projects it has references to the old path, but when I've replaced all of these that doesn't have an effect either

Comment: I just downloaded your repo, installed requirements and ran the server without any problems. Something is messed up with your environment. Delete your old env and create one making sure you use `-p python3.7`, then install your requirements again and run it.

Comment: It worked!!! You are now my new best friend. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. Best of luck!